# What's the circuit diagram symbol for a variable reluctance sensor transducer?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, symbol, diagram, transducer

I know I've seen the symbol before, it's something like a circle with an open triangle facing in the direction of current flow with a line through the middle. I'm specifically thinking of the transducers in electric guitar pickups. I've seen the symbol before but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams](https://www.noao.edu/ets/Mechanical/Policies/ANSI%20Y32.2-1975.pdf#page=56)

> 2.11 Transducer
>
> Accelerometer
>
> Motional Pickup Transducer
>
> Use only if a more specific symbol is not applicable, e.g., tachometer generator, microphone, motor, loudspeaker, etc.
>
> 2.11.1 General, electrical output

[image: Tranducer]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the graphic symbol for a variable reluctance speed sensor.

[image]