# Is there a circuit symbol for an accelerometer?

Tags: symbol, diagram

I use an analog accelerometer in a circuit, but I can't find a corresponding circuit symbol. Is there such a thing, or, where could I search for it besides [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbol).

Comment: Another refernece: https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/sensors-transducers-symbols.htm. I think anything that it should involve the concept of 3D axes, but don't know if there is a standard symbol for it yet. Good question, though.

Comment: See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/436614/87069). The symbol given there can be used for the accelerometer too.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=accelerometer+symbol&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908&sxsrf=APq-WBtqvXh6i_oKmqgCjCUlcZI-Whhmmw:1648381738528&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0req_nOb2AhVPPcAKHeJaAkYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1358&bih=722&dpr=1.25

Comment: Either the generic transducer symbol (the slashed square) or simply a square with the part number and the relevant pins (i.e. an IC)